# Visual Studio 2017 (version 15.7.3) - C#: the system cannot find the file specified

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

This issue started to happen after I upgraded to VS2017 (15.7.3)

Even for the very simple / default project, I cannot debug/run from the menu.
I get the error:

> The system cannot find the file specified

Note: I am 100% the project is compiled successfully. there is already an exe file (which works if I run it directly)

[image]

Comment: Where are the projects stored? Maybe its a permissions related issue? Can you create a solution in an older version of Visual Studio, reference the project and verify if it works or fails.

Comment: i created a new default project in c:/temp
it is an open folder

Comment: Can you load it into a solution from another version of Visual Studio and run it from that environment?

Comment: Well here are some suggestions run VS as admin, try another version of VS, clean and build the solution and check settings under Tools->Options->Debugging

Comment: thanks for your ideas

I tried loading projects from older version. they don't work
I tried to open VS as admin. same issue

What to check under Tools-Options-Debugging?

Comment: I've never performed this, but it helped a co-worker of mine once [Clear Visual Studio Component Cache](https://github.com/Codealike/Codealike-KnowledgeBase/blob/master/clear-visual-studio-component-cache.md)

Comment: I was only suggesting the debug options had you changed the default settings. I would say if you haven't made many modifications to the IDE after updating/installing the options shouldn't need changing. It may still be helpful to review them in general.

Comment: i did Install Repair - also didn't help

Comment: So you also tried to clear the component cache? I'm almost tempted at this rate to say reinstall. Do you have any more information about the error? Anything in the Windows event logs?

Comment: I even deleted this whole folder and started VS: <<userpath>>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_56449b86

it didn't help.

I also tried devenv.exe /Log in order to get some log but nothing in the log regarding this error :(

Comment: Honestly after going through this much trouble I'd try a reinstall.

Comment: Is the path for the file longer then 240 characters?

Comment: The path is not long. It is under c:/temp

Comment: @580 i did uninstall and install again . now it works.
pity!

Comment: Glad to hear it works! I can provide an answer or you can self-supply an answer just to wrap the post up.

Comment: @580 go ahead and will vote for it
although i don't like this solution :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**TL;DR** No exact cause was determined for this specific issue. The nuclear option of reinstalling Visual Studio remedied this issue. Below are some possible solutions to try with no guarantee any will work.

Most issues similar to this one that I've experienced a reinstall would remedy the issue.

---

**Permissions**

1. Run Visual Studio as administrator.
2. Verify that the Visual Studio process is running as the appropriate user by using Task Manager.
3. Verify that you're logged into the correct user within Visual Studio itself. Can try logging in and out.

**Visual Studio Specific**

1. Close and re-open Visual Studio.
2. Determine if the issue is specific to all installed versions of Visual Studio or just the current Visual Studio version. Attempt to debug the project from multiple versions of Visual Studio. This will not solve the issue, but may help to narrow the overall scope of the issue.
3. If debugging options in "Tools->Options->Debugging" have been modified check over the settings.
4. Sometimes Visual Studio itself can get into a funky state so attempt to clear its various caches. Here is an example of how to clear the component cache. [Github - Clear Visual Studio Component Cache](https://github.com/Codealike/Codealike-KnowledgeBase/blob/master/clear-visual-studio-component-cache.md)
5. Attempt a repair on the Visual Studio install by going to the *Control Panel's Program and Features* view right click the Visual Studio install and select "Change" in the context menu. The Visual Studio installer will open. Use the "Repair" utility. Alternatively, if the thought is it is a specific installed component failing attempt to reinstall the specific component using the "Modify" option.
6. At this point it may just be best to uninstall Visual Studio completely and reinstall it.

**Project Specific**

1. Instead of performing a rebuild, perform a clean then a build.
2. Additionally, if the step above does not give positive results use File Explorer to review what files persist after a clean operation. It may be that the clean operation didn't clean out all files. Such as those manually copied into the bin.
3. Attempt to run the project without using the debugger. This can be done from within Visual Studio or File Explorer. In Visual Studio (2010/2012/2013/2015/2017) the default hot key is currently *"Ctrl + F5"*. Otherwise, in the toolbar at the top of VS use the select *"Debug -> Start Without Debugging"*. Through File Explorer navigate to the projects *bin* directory run the process from there by double clicking. If it runs properly from any of these scenarios and not with the debugger attached it is something to do with the debugger. It may at this point just be easiest to reinstall VS.
4. If **(and only if)** you're familiar with the project (.csproj) and solution (.sln) layouts review them with a text editor. Make any necessary modifications.

**Other**

1. Verify path length does not exceed Windows max path length of 260 characters. [MSDN - Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx)
2. Check Windows Event Logs.
3. Use the command line utilities that come with Visual Studio and their varying switch options to attempt to diagnose the issue. [MSDN - /Log (devenv.exe)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/log-devenv-exe)

Comment: Thanks for organizing everything.
All the above ideas did not help , only re-install worked.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this same error and what was causing it was I had set up some post build events to clean out unnecessary directories for foreign languages from my bin folder.  But when VS Studio couldn't find those directories, it would show these warning messages (Can't find missing files), so I removed my post build event because it was no longer needed and that fixed the issue.

So basically I would check the Pre or Post Build Events for the project before going nuclear reinstalling everything:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem in visual studio with dot net project. Then I change the file location and it works for me. so I suggest you to change the file location and reopen visual studio

Comment: I think its an answer because in my case it works fine.